# Remove all Linux Distro's and keep Linux Mint

Tags: linux, partition, delete

Long time ago, I was experimenting with Linux. And by experimenting, I mean installing some Linux Distro's on my main PC to see which Linux Distro I like. And now I want to remove 2 out of 3 Distro's, but I'm scared that if I would delete only the partitions that the GRUB would be bricked. I also want to keep my Windows 11 for gaming.

It's worth noting that I have 3x 1TB disk and 1 500GB disk.

The Linux Distro's that I have and want to remove are:

- Pop_OS (was on `/dev/sda/` but it's somehow replaced with Fedora?)
- Fedora (`/dev/sda/`, `/dev/sdc/`, `/dev/sdd/`)

If someone has the answer, please tell it because I still can't find the answer. Thank you

Comment: Run the report only, just to see what is where: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Be sure to boot into the install you want to keep and totally reinstall grub from it, so it is your default boot.